# Am I taking this derivative correctly?

Tags: functions, derivatives

I'm having trouble verifying this, so could someone help me with this? I'm not quite sure if I'm taking this derivative correctly.

Given:

$\theta=\theta (t)$

$R=$constant

$q=$constant

Find:

$$\frac{d}{dt}(E)=\frac{d}{dt} \left ( \frac{1}{2}m \left (R^2\sin^2\theta \left  (\frac{d\theta}{dt} \right )^2 +R^2\cos^2\theta \left  (\frac{d\theta}{dt} \right )^2 +q^2 \left (\frac{d\theta}{dt} \right )^2 \right ) \right )$$

My attempt:

$\frac{dE}{dt}=$

$$\left ( \frac{1}{2}m \left (R^2\left (2\sin^2\theta  \frac{d\theta}{dt}  \frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2} +\sin(2\theta) \frac{d\theta}{dt}\frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2} \right ) +R^2 \left (2\cos^2\theta \frac{d\theta}{dt}\frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2}-2\sin\theta \cos\theta\frac{d\theta}{dt} \right ) +2q^2\frac{d\theta}{dt} \frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2} \right ) \right )$$

Based on the answers, this should be the correct solution:
$$=\left ( \frac{1}{2}m \left (R^2\left (2\sin^2\theta  \frac{d\theta}{dt}  \frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2} +\sin(2\theta) \frac{d\theta}{dt}(\frac{d\theta}{dt})^2 \right ) +R^2 \left (2\cos^2\theta \frac{d\theta}{dt}\frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2}-2\sin\theta \cos\theta\frac{d\theta}{dt} (\frac{d\theta}{dt})^2 \right ) +2q^2\frac{d\theta}{dt} \frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2} \right ) \right )$$

Answer (score 1):

Your function simplifies to $$\frac12m(R^2+q^2)\dot\theta^2\ !$$

Then the derivative,

$$m(R^2+q^2)\dot\theta\ddot\theta.$$

Comment: Yes, starting off by simplifying is a better idea.

Comment: I don't really understand this notation so I'm a bit confused...I know that the $\theta$ with the dot over it just means the time derivative of $\theta$, but then why do you have a factorial symbol? And where did the sines and cosines go?

Comment: @whatwhatwhat There is no factorial, just an exclamation mark !

Comment: Oh ok. Then what about the cosines and sines?

Comment: @whatwhatwhat: hem, read your formula.

Comment: Oh...nevermind...got it....

Answer (score 0):

You have the idea but you made a pair of similar careless errors.

The $\sin(2\theta) \frac{d\theta}{dt} \frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2} $ should instead read
 $\sin(2\theta) \frac{d\theta}{dt} \left(\frac{d\theta}{dt} \right)^2$.  A similar error appears in the other place where you had a function of $\theta$ multiplied by $\left(\frac{d\theta}{dt} \right)^2$.

Comment: I see what you mean by the first error but where is the second one?